# CSS Animation: Different color for Width-Animation

Tags: css, animation

I have a DIV with "width: 100%", and after some time it moves to a different width (for example "width: 50%") with a nice transition. I want that the part which is going to decrease to get a different color. How do I do it?

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
}

.bar {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

[image: Graphical example how it should be]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please embed images in the post

Comment: I wonder what should happen to the black area. Should it disappear when the animation of the red area have stopped, or should it fade away during/after the animation?

Comment: @RickardElimää it should "slide" to the left! In the first second it should be Black, than slide to the left and "disapear"..

Comment: Ah, I see. Just to be sure, the red area should instantaneousness update to the new width and the black area then animates to the new set width?

Comment: @RickardElimää yes, exactly! Sorry, english isnt my first language and its hard to descripe for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply put another bar exactly behind this bar. Set it's z-index to 1. And your current bar's z-index to a higher number.
The bar that is in the back, has a black color like you wanted. 
Now when the red bar decrease it's width, the one in the back becomes visible.

Comment: i thought about that, but than i have to use position: absolute; and then "width: 100%" doesnt work anymore :(

Comment: It works that way if i use "Position: inherit". Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses a linear-gradient where I animate the `background-size`. I placed a fully black gradient on the `.container`, and a red one on the `.bar`, where I put a `transition: background-size 1s` on the black `.container`.

By using javascript to change a CSS variable, I can get the bar to animate.

Added a range to show-case the result.

Do note that it's always better to specify what attribute to animate with `transiation`, because otherwise the browser loops through *all* animatable properies, which can create janky animations.

```js
let rangeInput = document.querySelector('input[type="range"');
let containerDiv = document.getElementById("container");

if (rangeInput) {
  rangeInput.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    let newValue = event.target.value;
    
    containerDiv.style.setProperty('--bar-width', `${newValue}%`);
  });
}
```

```css
input[type="range"] {
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

#container {
  --bar-width: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(black, black);
  transition: background-size 1s;
}

/* added "div" to obtain a higher specificity, to override the default background properties. */
div#container,
div.bar
{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: var(--bar-width);
}

.bar {
  background: linear-gradient(red, red);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>

<input type="range" value="100" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, the most basic working example.
(Try hovering the bar and see it moving)

By simply overlaying a pseudo-element over the static `.bar` element, with `position:absolute`, it is places above the bar and has dynamic width which you should change.

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
}

/* static background bar */
.bar {
  --progress: 80%; /* css variable */
  position: relative;
  background-color: salmon;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* This is the part which moves: */
.bar::before{
  content: '';
  background-color: darkred;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  width: var(--progress);
  transition: 1s;
}

.bar:hover {
  --progress: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```